# Какие ограничения полей по типу данных и размерности в REST API Shopify?

Tags: minishop2, field

Есть приложение которое позволяет создавать и редактировать как сами продукты, так и их варианты. Используются практически все поля!
  Необходимо получить ограничения для всех полей что бы избежать ошибок.
  К примеру, **price** имеет формат **хххххххх.хх**. Два символа поле после точки(именно точки), но вот сколь перед ней, не понятно. Приходиться принудительно отправлять заведомо огромное число что бы увидеть ответ от Shopify.

[Тут](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product) инфы почти нет.

Может кто то знает где найти такую информацию или поделитесь ссылкой!

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для продуктов информацию можно найти [здесь](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#update-2019-10).

Для вариантов [здесь](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant#update-2019-10).

Однако исчерпывающей информации там нет.